# Cursor release event is not triggering in teechart

Tags: c#, teechart

I am using teechart cursor tool and using its "change" event, which gets call each and every time when we move cursor of chart, but I want a event/function which gets call when we release cursor after moving.

```
this.cursorTool1.Change += new Steema.TeeChart.Tools.CursorChangeEventHandler(this.cursorTool1_Change);
```

Sample code :-

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Steema.TeeChart.Samples
{
    public class Tool_Cursor : Samples.BaseForm
{
    private Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line lineSeries1;
    private Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line lineSeries2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    private Steema.TeeChart.Axis axis1;
    private Steema.TeeChart.Tools.CursorTool cursorTool1;
    private Steema.TeeChart.Tools.CursorTool cursorTool2;
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

private bool flag;

    public Tool_Cursor()
    {
        // This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent();

        this.lineSeries1.FillSampleValues(100);
        this.lineSeries2.FillSampleValues(100);
        this.tChart1.Axes.Left.AutomaticMinimum = false;
        this.tChart1.Axes.Left.Minimum = 0.0;
        this.lineSeries2.CustomVertAxis = this.axis1;
  this.tChart1.BeforeDrawSeries += new PaintChartEventHandler(tChart1_BeforeDrawSeries);
  flag = true;

        this.cursorTool1.Pen.Color = Color.Navy;
        this.cursorTool1.Pen.Style = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash; 
        this.cursorTool1.Pen.Width = 2;

        this.cursorTool2.Pen.Color = Color.Plum;
        this.cursorTool2.Pen.Style = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot; 
        this.cursorTool2.Pen.Width = 2;

    }

void tChart1_BeforeDrawSeries(object sender, Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.Graphics3D g)
{
  if (flag)
  {
    // place upper series cursor in the middle
    this.cursorTool1.XValue = 0.5 * (this.lineSeries1.XValues.Maximum + this.lineSeries1.XValues.Minimum);
    flag = false;
  }
}

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
    {
        if( disposing )
        {
            if (components != null) 
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose( disposing );
    }

    #region Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Tool_Cursor));
        this.lineSeries1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line();
        this.lineSeries2 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line();
        this.axis1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Axis(this.components);
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.checkBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this.checkBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.cursorTool1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Tools.CursorTool();
        this.cursorTool2 = new Steema.TeeChart.Tools.CursorTool();
        this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.chartContainer.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(406, 56);
        this.textBox1.Text = "Cursor Tool is used to display vertical and / or horizontal lines on top of chart" +
            "s. Cursors can be dragged by mouse or by code at runtime. They notify position c" +
            "hanges with the OnChange event.";
        // 
        // panel1
        // 
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.checkBox2);
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.checkBox1);
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 56);
        this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(406, 52);
        // 
        // tChart1
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
        this.tChart1.Aspect.ZOffset = 0;
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.tChart1.Axes.Custom.Add(this.axis1);
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.tChart1.Axes.Left.EndPosition = 50;
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.tChart1.Axes.Left.Labels.Font.Brush.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        this.tChart1.Axes.Left.Labels.Font.Size = 7;
        this.tChart1.Axes.Left.Labels.Font.SizeFloat = 7F;
        this.tChart1.Axes.Left.LogarithmicBase = 2;
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.tChart1.Header.Lines = new string[] {
    "Cursor tool example"};
        this.tChart1.Header.Visible = false;
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.tChart1.Panel.Brush.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(254)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
        this.tChart1.Series.Add(this.lineSeries1);
        this.tChart1.Series.Add(this.lineSeries2);
        this.tChart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(406, 155);
        this.tChart1.Tools.Add(this.cursorTool1);
        this.tChart1.Tools.Add(this.cursorTool2);
        this.tChart1.AfterDraw += new Steema.TeeChart.PaintChartEventHandler(this.tChart1_AfterDraw);
        // 
        // chartContainer
        // 
        this.chartContainer.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 108);
        this.chartContainer.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(406, 155);
        // 
        // lineSeries1
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.lineSeries1.Brush.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(68)))), ((int)(((byte)(102)))), ((int)(((byte)(163)))));
        this.lineSeries1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(68)))), ((int)(((byte)(102)))), ((int)(((byte)(163)))));
        this.lineSeries1.ColorEach = false;
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.lineSeries1.LinePen.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(41)))), ((int)(((byte)(61)))), ((int)(((byte)(98)))));
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.lineSeries1.Marks.Callout.ArrowHead = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.ArrowHeadStyles.None;
        this.lineSeries1.Marks.Callout.ArrowHeadSize = 8;
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.lineSeries1.Marks.Callout.Brush.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.lineSeries1.Marks.Callout.Distance = 0;
        this.lineSeries1.Marks.Callout.Draw3D = false;
        this.lineSeries1.Marks.Callout.Length = 10;
        this.lineSeries1.Marks.Callout.Style = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.PointerStyles.Rectangle;
        this.lineSeries1.Marks.Callout.Visible = false;
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.lineSeries1.Pointer.Style = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.PointerStyles.Rectangle;
        this.lineSeries1.Title = "line1";
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.lineSeries1.XValues.DataMember = "X";
        this.lineSeries1.XValues.Order = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.ValueListOrder.Ascending;
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.lineSeries1.YValues.DataMember = "Y";
        // 
        // lineSeries2
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.lineSeries2.Brush.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(243)))), ((int)(((byte)(156)))), ((int)(((byte)(53)))));
        this.lineSeries2.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(243)))), ((int)(((byte)(156)))), ((int)(((byte)(53)))));
        this.lineSeries2.ColorEach = false;
        this.lineSeries2.CustomVertAxis = this.axis1;
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.lineSeries2.LinePen.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(146)))), ((int)(((byte)(94)))), ((int)(((byte)(32)))));
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.lineSeries2.Marks.Callout.ArrowHead = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.ArrowHeadStyles.None;
        this.lineSeries2.Marks.Callout.ArrowHeadSize = 8;
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.lineSeries2.Marks.Callout.Brush.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.lineSeries2.Marks.Callout.Distance = 0;
        this.lineSeries2.Marks.Callout.Draw3D = false;
        this.lineSeries2.Marks.Callout.Length = 10;
        this.lineSeries2.Marks.Callout.Style = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.PointerStyles.Rectangle;
        this.lineSeries2.Marks.Callout.Visible = false;
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.lineSeries2.Pointer.Style = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.PointerStyles.Rectangle;
        this.lineSeries2.Title = "line2";
        this.lineSeries2.VertAxis = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.VerticalAxis.Custom;
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.lineSeries2.XValues.DataMember = "X";
        this.lineSeries2.XValues.Order = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.ValueListOrder.Ascending;
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.lineSeries2.YValues.DataMember = "Y";
        // 
        // axis1
        // 
        this.axis1.Horizontal = false;
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.axis1.Labels.Font.Brush.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        this.axis1.Labels.Font.Size = 7;
        this.axis1.Labels.Font.SizeFloat = 7F;
        this.axis1.OtherSide = false;
        this.axis1.StartPosition = 50;
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 7);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 13);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.UseMnemonic = false;
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this.label2.AutoSize = true;
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 26);
        this.label2.Name = "label2";
        this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 13);
        this.label2.TabIndex = 1;
        this.label2.UseMnemonic = false;
        // 
        // checkBox1
        // 
        this.checkBox1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.checkBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(107, 12);
        this.checkBox1.Name = "checkBox1";
        this.checkBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(53, 23);
        this.checkBox1.TabIndex = 2;
        this.checkBox1.Text = "&Snap";
        this.checkBox1.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.checkBox1_CheckedChanged);
        // 
        // checkBox2
        // 
        this.checkBox2.Checked = true;
        this.checkBox2.CheckState = System.Windows.Forms.CheckState.Checked;
        this.checkBox2.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.checkBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(167, 12);
        this.checkBox2.Name = "checkBox2";
        this.checkBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(72, 23);
        this.checkBox2.TabIndex = 3;
        this.checkBox2.Text = "&Active";
        this.checkBox2.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.checkBox2_CheckedChanged);
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(247, 12);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 4;
        this.button1.Text = "&Edit...";
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // cursorTool1
        // 
        this.cursorTool1.Series = this.lineSeries1;
        this.cursorTool1.Style = Steema.TeeChart.Tools.CursorToolStyles.Vertical;
        this.cursorTool1.Change += new Steema.TeeChart.Tools.CursorChangeEventHandler(this.cursorTool1_Change);
        // 
        // cursorTool2
        // 
        this.cursorTool2.FollowMouse = true;
        this.cursorTool2.Series = this.lineSeries2;
        this.cursorTool2.Change += new Steema.TeeChart.Tools.CursorChangeEventHandler(this.cursorTool2_Change);
        // 
        // Tool_Cursor
        // 
        this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 13);
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(406, 263);
        this.Name = "Tool_Cursor";
        this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.panel1.PerformLayout();
        this.chartContainer.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }
    #endregion

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.cursorTool1.Snap = this.checkBox1.Checked;
        this.cursorTool1.Style = Steema.TeeChart.Tools.CursorToolStyles.Vertical;
    }

    private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.cursorTool1.Active = this.checkBox2.Checked;
    }

    private void tChart1_AfterDraw(object sender, Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.Graphics3D g)
    {
        Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.Graphics3D gr = this.tChart1.Graphics3D;
        // TODO : add custom horizontal line where the axes meet
    }

    private void cursorTool1_Change(object sender, Steema.TeeChart.Tools.CursorChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        // show the cursor values...
        this.label1.Text = "X="+e.XValue.ToString("#.00");
    }

    private void cursorTool2_Change(object sender, Steema.TeeChart.Tools.CursorChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        // show the cursor values...
        this.label2.Text = "X="+e.XValue.ToString("#.00")+"; Y="+e.YValue.ToString("#.00");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        TeeChart.Editors.Tools.ToolsEditor.ShowEditor(this.cursorTool1);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding in a MouseUp event and checked if the CursorTool was clicked, e.g.

```
        this.cursorTool1.Pen.Width = 2;

        tChart1.MouseUp += TChart1_MouseUp;



  this.cursorTool2.Pen.Color = Color.Plum;
        this.cursorTool2.Pen.Style = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot; 
        this.cursorTool2.Pen.Width = 2;

    }

    private void TChart1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var clicked = cursorTool1.Clicked(e.X, e.Y);

        if(clicked == Tools.CursorClicked.Vertical) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Cursed has been released!");
        }
    }
```